# How to visualize more attributes of a dimension in Pivot table in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, ssas, pivot-table, dimensional-modeling

I have a SSAS cube where one dimension is "User".

User has many attributes, say "Email", "Mobile Number", "Address" and (many) more.

I build a Pivot table in Excel 2016 where I can easily find which Users, for instance, placed orders in the current month.

Now, I want to visualize for each of these users several of the possible attributes: I just need to easily get the list of email and mobile numbers of the users that placed orders in the current month.

If I drag the required attributes in the Pivot table though, these are used to further split each row: under each User in the Pivot there will be a level with just one Mobile Phone and this will be further divided in one email and so on.

What I need is, instead, keeping the division of the Fact "Order" only by the dimension User, and for each User to just visualize some more fields.
What's the best way to achieve this?

The only way we can think of so far is to have an additional attribute with the concatenation (comma separated?) of all the needed information. But this is honestly horrible. The aim should be to have each of the additional attributes in its own excel cell.

Comment: "Show details" is not an option. It is limited to N rows and it is not nice visually, there are many keys shown as useless (for the end user) numbers. The additional attributes should be visibile in the Pivot or besides it, if possible. "Show details" would be great if it were customizable (show me these attributes) and not limited in the number of rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this ...

1. Pivot-Table options -> Display -> Classic PivotTable layout
2. For each field on your pivot table, Field Settings->Subtotals->None

From this raw data ...

[image]

And the options above, I generate this Pivot Table ...

[image]

Comment: (1) I will mark yours as an answer because it is actually working. It does have a problem though: the more attributes of User I add, the slower it gets (unbearably). It seems like it is actually dividing the fact for all the attributes and then hiding the rows in eccess instead of just getting the additional fields and putting them side by side with the key attribute of the dimension.
In your example, it seems like it is actually dividing all the (two) orders of Name10 by all the possible email and then showing only the row where name10 has, as an email, "Name10@somemail.com".

Comment: (2):This requires much more work than just finding in the raw data the email of Name10. I guess this is inevitable as it is not granted that Name10 only used 1 email.
In my data structure though, there is a dimension table Users where each user has got only 1 email (each row in that table is 1 user and the userID is a PK).

Comment: (3):So in my case it seems it is doing a lot of unnecessary slow work.
Thank you anyways, yours is already a good improvement!

Comment: The order of the fields in the rows may make a difference for speed, but typically you lay them out how you want to view them.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on Excel 2016, as I'm using XL 2013.

But in my pivot table, I can right-click on the default-displayed value for the dimension (I guess this would show the user Name for your User dimension - for me it's a Products dimension).[[image: Show member properties[1]]

Then select "Show Properties in Report", and select the one you want.

What it shows is what you get in the Tooltip popup when you hover over the cell.  It doesn't seem to treat these extra values as extra dimension levels, with a Cartesian-product relation to the leaf-level you're looking at: it correctly just reads one value per leaf member.

Is there maybe some switch in your dimension design you need to flip to get Excel to do this?  My dimension has these "properties" as dimension attributes, with AttributeHierarchyVisible=True, AttributeHierarchyEnabled=False.

I only have 2 of these defined (Current Product Code and ID).  For some reason this Excel functionality also includes the immediate parent level of the leaf level in the hierarchy (Category) as a "property".